# inverse Gamma Distribution and LogNormal Distribution can both discribe the data, is that a coincidence?

Tags: fitting, gamma-distribution, lognormal-distribution

I am observing the fluxes of source and I am trying to learn something from it's distribution of fluxes.

When I histogram my data, I can  perfectly describe my data with a lognormal distribution. That was in fact what I had expected, but I was still curious if I could find other description for the flux distribution.

From a physical model point of few, a scenario where the fluxes are distributed according to the gamma distribution would make sense (for which I have a mind-picture of "events for which a waiting time is relevant").

To my disappointment the Gamma Distribution did a very poor job in describing the data. In a trail and error approach, I went forth and fitted the flux distribution with the Inverse Gamma Distribution. I found it to be a **perfect fit** for my data, even better than LogNormal distribution (not significantly in a chi^2 sense though).

I am now a bit dumb-struck:

First, because I don't have a "mind picture" for the inverse gamma distribution. Does it ever occur in *nature* other than being a vehicle for Bayesian interference? Could you provide such a "mind picture"?

Second, is there any reason for the Inverse Gamma distribution to fit some exponential data, other than it being a "flexible function" (flexible in a sense that I could probably fit a polynomial of some order to may data as well).

Comment: Presumably a "flux" is a rate of something per unit time.  Re-express them in terms of time per unit total flux: that is, take their reciprocals.  That doesn't change the *meaning* of the data, but if originally they had an inverse-gamma distribution, the reciprocals have a gamma distribution; and if originally they had a lognormal distribution, then they still have a lognormal distribution.  Thus, your situation no longer seems terribly exotic: you are wondering under what circumstances data might be approximated by either a gamma or lognormal distribution.

Comment: Uh, this sounds promising! The flux in the light curve is in units of energy at a given time, but I guess this makes the histogram in units of 1/flux. Could you provide me with some further reading on what reciprocals mean in statstics (that is a badly worded question, but I is it clear what I need? just some further reading, or a "real life example"? Thanks already.

Comment: Reciprocal flux has a natural interpretation as the amount of time needed to transmit a unit of energy. Good books on exploratory data analysis include a lot of discussion about "re-expressing" or "transforming" variables.  John Tukey's book *EDA* is a notable resource.  You can find a lot about this on our site, too, under the name [Box-Cox transformation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Box-Cox+transformation+score%3A2): the reciprocal is essentially the same as a Box-Cox transformation of power -1.

Comment: Does any simple distribution really "occur in nature"? In general, they're just approximations (sometimes really, really good ones). I've used inverse Gamma distributions a few times (e.g. on insurance claim sizes where the lognormal wasn't skewed enough; it worked remarkably well for some particular kinds of data) and I've seen even more strongly skewed inverse Gaussian distributions used a few times (e.g. for [earthquakes](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10950-019-09822-5)) but in each case *using* it doesn't mean that it was anything more than a useful approximation.

Comment: i.e. consider the advice of George Box ... "*Remember that all models are wrong. The practical question is how wrong do they have to be to not be useful.*" $\:$ Now, to differentiate between a lognormal and something more right skew (including the inverse gamma), look at the *log*. If it's still right skew, you can rule out the two-parameter lognormal. Now for your inverse gamma (as long as the shape parameter isn't too small), take the cube root of the reciprocal; if that's not pretty close to normally distributed, the inverse gamma would be ruled out.

Comment: In fact its log right-skwedness was the reason I found the Gamma distribution, but "proofing it" will be hard as we cant sample the tails well. Thank you very much for the paper reference, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Would either of you know more similar papers, reviews, or easy too read books (I'm traveling so i haven't been able to look at Tukey's)? One point where my case differs from the typical statistician's is that I'm not so much interested in predicting, but getting cues about the process at work (e.g. lognormal: gaussians multiplied vs gamma: poisson with wait times (?))